# Problem with NDSolve in Mathematica 9 / 10

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I'm having trouble by solving the following differential equation in *Mathematica* 9 and 10, where the code works fine in version 7:

```
τp = 200*10^(-15); 
e = 1.60217653*10^(-19); 
me = 9.1093826*10^(-31); 
c = 2.99792458*10^(8); 
ϵ = 8.854187817*10^(-12); 
h = 6.626*10^(-34); 
hbar = h/(2 Pi);  
λ = 786*10^(-9);
n0 = 1.45; 
mred = 0.635*me ;
Eg = 7.5*e;
τr = 220*10^(-15);
ω = (2 Pi c)/λ;
k0 = (n0 ω/c);
rhocrit = (ϵ*mred*ω^2/(e^2));
H = 2*10^(4);
I0 = H*(2 Sqrt[Log[2]])/(τp Sqrt[Pi]);
Int1[t_] := I0*Exp[-4 Log[2] (t^2/τp^2)];
γ[Int_] := (ω/e)*Sqrt[(mred c n0 ϵ Eg)/(2 Int)];
Γ[Int_] := γ[Int]^2/(1 + γ[Int]^2);
ζ[Int_] := 1/(1 + γ[Int]^2);
β[Int_] := Pi^2/(2 EllipticK[ζ[Int]]*EllipticE[ζ[Int]]);
x[Int_] := (2 Eg)/(Pi hbar ω Sqrt[Γ[Int]])*EllipticE[ζ[Int]];
μ[Int_] := IntegerPart[x[Int] + 1] - x[Int];
Q[Int_] := 
  Sqrt[(Pi)/(2 EllipticK[ζ[Int]])] 
    Sum[
      Exp[-s Pi ((EllipticK[Γ[Int]] - EllipticE[Γ[Int]]) / 
        (EllipticE[ζ[Int]]))] DawsonF[Sqrt[β[Int] (s + 2 μ[Int])]], 
      {s, 0, 5}];
WPI[Int_] := 
  If[10^(3) > Int, 
     0, 
     (2 ω)/(9 Pi) *((ω mred )/(hbar Sqrt[Γ[Int]]))^(3/2)*Q[Int]*
       Exp[-Pi ((EllipticK[Γ[Int]] - EllipticE[Γ[Int]])/
         (EllipticE[ζ[Int]]))*IntegerPart[x[Int] + 1]]];
Ekrit[t_] := Eg (1 + 1/(4 γ[Int1[t]]^2));
Ekin[t_] := Ekrit[t]/10;

s1 = 
  NDSolve[{sol1'[t] == WPI[Int1[t]] + 
    (((k0 ω ((16 Pi ϵ^2 Sqrt[mred Ekin[t]^3]) /
               (Sqrt[2]*e^4*sol1[t])))/
         (n0^2 rhocrit 
           (1 + ω^2*(((16 Pi ϵ^2 Sqrt[mred Ekin[t]^3]) / 
              (Sqrt[2]*e^4*sol1[t]))^2)))) sol1[t] Int1[t])/
      (Eg) - sol1[t]/τr, sol1[-3 τp] == 1}, 
    sol1, {t, -3.1 τp, 4 τp}];
```

In version 7 there are no error messages and with:

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[sol1[t] /. s1], {t, -2 τp, 2τp}]
```

I get the expected result:

[image]

But when I use one of the newer versions, the kernel shuts down without giving an output. Anyone got an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please format the code of your question such that it can be copied to Mathematica?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first question in here and I had a bit trouble formatting the code, but now it should work ;)

Comment: @Peter can you share the original equation?

Comment: @m0nhawk thanks for your editing suggestions! what do you mean with original equation?

Comment: If it shuts down, then I'd report this to the support. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @Peter Can you also provide the PC configuration, time taken to compute this. It shuts down with "Out of memory" error.

Comment: PC configuration: Windows 8.1 64-Bit, Intel Core i7-4702MQ, 8 GB RAM. In Mathematica 7 the whole code takes 2 seconds to evaluate in Version 9 there is absolutely no output, not even out of memory error. It just gives a short sound and clears all of the definitions made before.

Comment: Your code generates several warnings in v9, Vista 32bit but gives the desired result. No warning in v8 BTW.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the definition of `Q`?  Is the `Sqrt` term supposed to be multiplied by the `Sum` term?  I don't know if this has any relation to your problem.

Comment: No, the definition of Q ist not the point. I get the same problem even with much easier functions.